# Sandbag modelling

Tags: sculpting, sculpt

just after some tips to model or sculpt a wall of sandbags realistically (ie not looking like a bunch of pillows). Especially where there’s creases pinching at the tied off area, and how to model the tied off area itself. Polycount isn’t a massive issue, as this will be for 3d resin printing.

Also how would you go around making the wall itself to make sure the sandbags look realistic in the sense that they sag a little and also easily follow a certain shape (eg like the curved wall below?)

[image]

Thanks in advance.